# Three.js ignore obscured objects using raycaster intersectObjects

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

The three.js Raycaster example shows how to highlight objects using intersectObjects:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onMouseMove( event ) {
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}

function render() {
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
    for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
        intersects[ i ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
    }
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster

However this intersects objects even if they are obscured behind another object. I've created a  demo showing that you can highlight objects even if they are behind the sphere object:

https://codepen.io/kmturley/pen/gObgKee

Notice how in the demo you can highlight objects behind the sphere. **How can we ignore objects which are obscured by other objects?** even if they exist within the Camera Frustrum and are rendered by Three.js?

My use-case is that I actually want to hide the objects which are at the back of the sphere and their labels.

Examples showing intersections:

- https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-align-html-elements-to-3d.html
- https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Click.html
- https://callumprentice.github.io/apps/country_selector/index.html
- http://jensljungblad.github.io/musicmap-globe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually was a very simple solve. intersectObjects actually returns Objects back in order of distance from the camera:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(points);
```

So by picking the first item in the array, you will always get the closest Object:

```
console.log(intersects[0].object);
```

The other thing I had to change was to include the Sphere in intersectObjects list, to ensure it would get picked before anything behind it:

```
var points = [];
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 20, 20);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, opacity: 0.2, transparent: true});
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);
points.push(sphere);
```

So intersectObjects includes the sphere, but then I ignore it as a selected Object in the following if statement:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(points);
if (intersects[0] && intersects[0].object !== sphere) {
  selected = intersects[0].object;
  selected.currentHex = selected.material.color.getHex();
  selected.material.color.setHex(0xffffff);
}
```

This demo now blocks objects which are behind the Sphere:

https://codepen.io/kmturley/pen/gObgKee